# App.xaml does not instantiate App resources

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, winrt-xaml, win-universal-app

I have an Universal App Project and I instantiate a View Model Locator and an IOC Configurator instance in the App.xaml file.
This will work... But if I add some other resources like styles or build other instances nothing will be created. If I add more than 6 or 7 resources no instances will be created... This is very strange. Does anybody know whats wrong there? Now I create the instances in the app code behind, but this can not be the way!

bye
Markus

Comment: You probably shouldn't be adding resources directly to your App.xaml. I also wonder if there is an error in one of the resources which causes the whole App.xaml to fail. Maybe try adding them one at a time to see if there is a singular one which causes the issue?

Comment: First I thought it has to do with any other framework I am using (MVVM Light). But I have tested it with an empty singular class and  after declaring 7 instances no instance will be created. The App.xaml is for adding resources - I thought... And in the past all worked correctly but this is the first universal app project... There is no directly error in app.xaml, only instances declared in it will not be instantiated...

Comment: Hi, Did you ever figure this out? I'm dealing with the same problem now in my Windows 10 Universal application.